# decryption error using AES

Tags: android

```
/**
 * 初始化 AES Cipher
 * @param sKey
 * @param cipherMode
 * @return
 */
public static Cipher initAESCipher (String sKey, int cipherMode) throws Exception {
    //创建Key gen
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = null;
    Cipher cipher = null;
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance( "SHA1PRNG" ,"Crypto");
        sr.setSeed(sKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        keyGenerator.init(128,sr);
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        byte[] codeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(codeFormat, "AES");
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        //初始化
        cipher.init(cipherMode, key);
    return cipher;
}

/**
 * 对文件进行AES加密
 * @param sourceFile
 * @param fileType
 * @param sKey
 * @return
 */
public static File encryptFile(File sourceFile,String fileType, String sKey) throws Exception {
    //新建临时加密文件
    File encrypfile = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;

        inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        encrypfile = new File(fileType);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(encrypfile);
        Cipher cipher = initAESCipher(sKey,Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
        //以加密流写入文件
        CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher);
        byte[] cache = new byte[1024];
        int nRead = 0;
        while ((nRead = cipherInputStream.read(cache)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(cache, 0, nRead);
            outputStream.flush();
        }
        cipherInputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            sourceFile.delete();

    return encrypfile;
}
```

I want to encrypt =and decrypt files using AES. This is my code.

```
/**
 * AES方式解密文件
 * @param sourceFile
 * @return
 */
public static File decryptFile(File sourceFile,String fileType,String sKey) throws Exception {
    File decryptFile = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
        decryptFile = new File(fileType);
        Cipher cipher = initAESCipher(sKey,Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(decryptFile);
        CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, cipher);
        byte [] buffer = new byte [1024];
        int r;
        while ((r = inputStream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            cipherOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, r);
        }
        cipherOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            sourceFile.delete();
    return decryptFile;
}
```

I use this to encrypt and decrypt file,but I got the following log:

```
02-22 17:36:38.451 11972-11995/com.augur.android.agcom W/System.err: java.io.IOException: pad block corrupted
```

Can anyone help me ? I have been confused for two weeks.

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Comment: Note that the code `SecureRandom.getInstance( "SHA1PRNG" ,"Crypto");` will fail on Android 7.0+ devices.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided a padding at instantiation of `Cipher.getInstance("AES")`.  It is best to supply both a padding option and a mode because the base documentation states: " provider-specific default values for the mode and padding scheme" and that may vary.

The initialization string should include the padding and mode.

Since no iv is being supplied perhaps ECB mode is being used, that is not secure but an initialization string would be: "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding". (PKCS#5 padding is archaic but is essentially the same as PKCS#7).

But don't use ECB mode, it is not secure, instead use CBC with a random IV and MAC the encrypted string for authentication.